# Bootstrap modals showing transparent background on iPhone8, iPhone11

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have some bootstrap modals in my website code and they are correctly showing on iPad, MAC, windows and android phone. But they are showing transparent background on iPhone8 and above. It is also working on iPhone 5.

```html
<!--Open camera modal-->
<div id="opencamera" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <!--Open camera modal-->
        <div id="opencamera" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h1 class="title">Camera Barcode Scan</h1>

                <div>
                  <a class="button" id="startButton">Start</a>
                  <a class="button" id="resetButton">Reset</a>
                </div>

                <div id="dave" style="visibility:hidden; height:1px;">
                  <video id="video" height="300" style="border: 1px solid gray"></video>
                </div>

                <div id="dave2" style="visibility:hidden; height:50px;">
                  <div id="sourceSelectPanel" style="display:none">
                    <label for="sourceSelect">Change video source:</label>
                    <select id="sourceSelect" style="max-width:400px">
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <code id="result" style="display:none"></code>

                <div>
                  <audio id="myAudio" preload="auto">
                        <source src="beep.wav" type="audio/wav">
                    </audio>
                  <button id="play" style="display:none">Click</button>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="addqtybtn" style="display:none" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addqty()">Next</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <h1 class="title">Camera Barcode Scan</h1>

        <div>
          <a class="button" id="startButton">Start</a>
          <a class="button" id="resetButton">Reset</a>
        </div>

        <div id="dave" style="visibility:hidden; height:1px;">
          <video id="video" height="300" style="border: 1px solid gray"></video>
        </div>

        <div id="dave2" style="visibility:hidden; height:50px;">
          <div id="sourceSelectPanel" style="display:none">
            <label for="sourceSelect">Change video source:</label>
            <select id="sourceSelect" style="max-width:400px">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <code id="result" style="display:none"></code>

        <div>
          <audio id="myAudio" preload="auto">
            <source src="beep.wav" type="audio/wav">
            </audio>
          <button id="play" style="display:none">Click</button>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="addqtybtn" style="display:none" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addqty()">Next</button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I am using above code to generate a bootstrap modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing fade class of parent div worked for me. Now, Modal is working fine for iPhone 8, iPhone 11